# Port QRegExp::exactMatch() in Qt6

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm porting a Qt5 application to Qt6. I want to move away from Qt5CoreCompat module of Qt6 as soon as possible. My problem is with `QRegExp` class which should be replaced with `QRegularExpression` class. Most patches are relatively trivial but how can I port [`QRegExp::exactMatch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#exactMatch) in Qt6. Here is some code from the application:

```cpp
QRegExp version(QLatin1String("(.+)_v(\\d+)"));
if (version.exactMatch(completeBaseName/*QString*/))
{
        // some code
}
```

I don't see a way to do this in `QRegularExpressionMatch` class. I guess solution might be something like this:

```cpp
QRegularExpression version(QLatin1String("(.+)_v(\\d+)"));
QRegularExpressionMatch match = version.match(completeBaseName);
if (match.hasMatch())
{
        // Find exact match or not
}
```

I want to have the same behavior as before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation suggests using the [`anchoredPattern` helper function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#anchoredPattern) to do the anchoring from the regular expression itself:

```
QRegularExpression version(QRegularExpression::anchoredPattern(QLatin1String("(.+)_v(\\d+)")));
```

Comment: It's QRegularExpression, not QRegularExression

Answer (score 4):

migrate qt5 [QRegExp::exactMatch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#exactMatch) to qt6 [QRegularExpression::match](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#match)

```bash
find . -name '*.cpp' |
xargs grep -l '\.exactMatch(' |
xargs sed -i -E 's/(.*?)\.exactMatch\((.*?)\)/\1.match(\2).hasMatch()/'
```

example

```
-    return someRegex.exactMatch(str);
+    return someRegex.match(str).hasMatch();
```

this assumes the regex is "anchored" with `^...$`

Comment: Hi @milahu, could you clarify, what sources did you check? I assume that Qt6, am I correct?

Comment: added links ...